# How can the constraint X is doubly stochastic be represented in a lagrangian function,

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to solve

min a'Xb

subject to X is doubly stochastic

how can i represent this constraint as a Lagrangian, i.e. I want G(X) in the following equation

a'Xb - trace(L'G(X))

where a, b are vectors, X is an n*n matrix

Comment: @ Reza_va , have you bothered to read my post ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $DS_n$ be the set of $n\times n$ doubly stochastic matrices, $f:X\in DS_n\rightarrow f(X)=a^TXb\in\mathbb{R}$.

$DS_n$ is a convex compact subset of $M_n(\mathbb{R})$. Since $f$ is linear, the minimum of $f$ is reached in an extremal point of $DS_n$, that is, in a permutation matrix (Birkhoff).

EDIT. To test all permutation matrices is not a good idea because the associated complexity is $O(n!)$. It is better to use linear programming: calculate $\min_Xa^TXb$ under the conditions $Xu-u=X^Tu-u=0$ and $x_{i,j}\geq 0$ (for example, in Maple, "LPSolve"); it seems that the complexity is in $O(n^{3.6})$.

Moreover the "binary programming" ($a_{i,j}\in[[0,1]]$) or the simplex algorithm are less efficient.

Comment: :) Sorry for not adding a comment on your post previously. Yes I read it and it was very useful. I changed it a little and applied it to my work. Many tanks

Comment: In addition, There is a theorem saying that: a'Xb (when X is a permutation matrix) is minimized when a and b are sorted in the reverse order and maximized if they are sorted in the same order

Comment: @ Reza_va , the proper use of this forum is that you upvote or you accept an answer (you give the green chevron) when you are satisfied with it. About your second comment, the indicated result is valid only if $x\geq 0,y\geq 0$.

Comment: @ Reza_va , correction about my last sentence; your second comment is valid for any real $x,y$.